# Event (delegates) - what's the danger of relying too much on them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

```
public delegate void Event_GameStart();
public static event Event_GameStart OnGameStart;

public delegate void Event_RunningStart();
public static event Event_RunningStart OnRunningStart;

public delegate void Event_PassiveSpeedIncrease();
public static event Event_PassiveSpeedIncrease OnSpeedIncrease;  

public static void Call_GameStarts ()
{
    OnGameStart?.Invoke();
}

public static void Call_RunningStarts()
{
    OnRunningStart?.Invoke();
}

public static void Call_SpeedIncrease()
{
    OnSpeedIncrease?.Invoke();
}
```

I love Unity events because I don't need every object to reference ParticleEffectManager, SfxManager, HUDManager etc. for every interaction that happens, I can decouple so many things.

But as I'm looking at this SceneEventsManager.cs that is just growing bigger and bigger, and I can see it having 20, even 100 events all in this one script, I'm starting to wonder if this is too much reliance on events. Could any experienced programmers tell me the danger of me doing this and if there is a better alternative?

Comment: Events are a C# feature, not a unity feature. The only downside I know of is that it takes insignificantly longer like virtual methods.

Comment: I think the main danger here already lies in having a `static` thing that apparently controls everything .. instead you should rather use proper references... and yes as mentioned above: [`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) and [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates) are general `c#` keywords and not Unity specific... [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) exists as type and therefore your title and description are a bit misleading ...

Comment: what you are creating is a quite controversial thing .. yes you are "decoupling" things since you don't need the reference ... **but** do you really? No, in fact you are strong coupling everything together to a complex event system in a hidden way! It might get quite difficult to understand later in which order things are called or what is actually invoked by whom and who will be listening

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, it's like all the scripts go through this one hub, nobody knows who comes through and in what order, all we know is if this messes up everything fails! XD

Comment: @SirMt exactly ;) Another pitfalls with events in Unity in particular with `static` ones: You have to be really careful to unregister any listener for an object before destroying it, otherwise you get exceptions every time the event is invoked